# Prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin n}{n}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

My guess is that it diverges because 1/n diverges and sin is bounded between [-1,1]; however, I know that the product of two divergent series may yield a convergent. Any suggestions of going about this?

Comment: This and more similar questions can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20n%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Wolfram says it converges to $ \frac{1}{2} (\pi - 1) $, but I can't immediately see how it gets there